# Embedded excel user control in C#

Tags: c#

I have a user control (in c#) with an embedded excel worksheet and other gridcontrols. I have this user control in a form. I need to print the form but I found that embedded excel worksheet is not supported in DevExpress Xtrareport. I can print the excel worksheet separately but I need to print the whole form not just that excel worksheet. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick down and dirty Print extension method. There's alot more that you can do as far as scaling the form and all that, but this should get you started. This method will print the form as is, and as is visible to the user.

```
    public static class FormExtensions
    {
        public static void PrintForm(this Form f)
        {
            PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
            document.PrintPage += (o, e) =>
            {
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(f.Width, f.Height);
                f.DrawToBitmap(image, e.PageBounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
            };
            document.Print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I print the form embedded excel worksheet does not appear. Any reason u know of?

Comment: I've never used control, so I'm not sure why that would happen. You can try to see if maybe you can get that control drawn to a bitmap in memory, and draw that onto the form's Bitmap.